# Not getting roles using a SSO identity framework 6 server

Tags: c#, duende-identity-server, identityserver6

I have been trying to make a login server to use as single sign on server for multiple applications but I can't seem to get roles on my client side of the application. When I check the roles in User.Claims nothing is there and [Authorize(roles = "Admin")] doesn't seem to work either

My current code is:

```cs
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                options.ClientId = "CRMERPClient";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.MapInboundClaims = false;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;


                // code flow + PKCE (PKCE is turned on by default)
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.UsePkce = true;
        
                options.Scope.Add("crm");
                options.Scope.Add("erp");

                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";

                options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role");
            });

        builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

^ My client side program.cs

```cs
            builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
            })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
                .AddServerSideSessions()
                .AddServerSideSessionStore<CustomServerSessionStore>()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential().AddProfileService<ProfileService>();

            builder.Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();
```

^ My Server side program.cs

```cs
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
        new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
        new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new ApiScope("crm", "CRM"),
            new ApiScope("erp", "ERP"),
            new ApiScope("dms", "DMS")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
        new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("crm")
            {
                Scopes = { "crm", "roles"}
            },

            new ApiResource("erp")
            {
                Scopes = { "erp", "roles"}
            },

            new ApiResource("dms")
            {
                Scopes = { "dms", "roles"}
            }
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "CRMERPClient",

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                // where to redirect after login
                RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:7218/signin-oidc" },

                // where to redirect after logout
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:7218/signout-callback-oidc" },

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                //https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/1_client_credentials/
                  AllowedScopes = { "crm", "erp",
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        JwtClaimTypes.Role
                    },
            },
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "DocumentManagementSystem",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

                RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:7218/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:7218/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile", "dms", "roles" }
            }
        };
```

^ My config of the Identity Server

```cs
    public class ProfileService : IProfileService
    {
        public ProfileService() { }

        public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
        {
            var roleClaims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
            context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

^And my profile Service

Am I missing something here? I tried to resolve the issue by following numerous tutorials and looking over stackoverflow but it was hard to find identity server 6 answers instead of identity server 4.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Not sure this will work but try changing JwtClaimTypes.Role to "roles" under AllowedScopes for your client. Since you're clearing the default mapping names in your app, it may be mapping to the defaults.

Comment: @GHDevOps, thank you for your reply. I just tried it out but it didn't work, also tried roles on the client instead of role but that gave the same results aswell.